# java swing JTabbedPane stateChangedEvent

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have added a change listener to a JTabbedPane
  The stateChanged should only process the change in tab
  i.e when i switch from index1 to index2 and not other stateChangedEvents

i.e I do not want this state listener to get invoked 
  on the following method calls

```
     jTabbedPane.removeTabAt(index)
           or this.tabbedPane.insertTab(tabTitle, null, jPanel,null,this.index);
jTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(index)
```

Is there a way i can do this.

```
 ChangeListener changeListener=new ChangeListener()
            {
              @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
              {
              };
           }
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not much clear from your question that what exactly you want, I think you are looking for  :

```
      tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {    
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println("change"); // Or what ever you want
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE :** This is what you can do, works

```
public class JTabbedPaneDemo {    
    static int tabCount;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        tabCount = tb.getTabCount(); // get total number of tabs
        tb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JTabbedPane jt = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
                if(tabCount == jt.getTabCount()){ // true if no tab is removed
                     System.out.println("change"); // Or what ever you want
                }
            }
        });
        tb.removeTabAt(0); // stateChange will be called but if will not be true
        tabCount = tb.getTabCount(); // update tabCount after tab remove
        ...  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 tabs .When i am in tab 3 and choose tab1 stateChaange gets invoked.It also gets invoked when i call tabbedPane.removeTabAt(1);I do not want this to be invoked when i call removeTabAt(1), It should be invoked only when i siwtch the tab

Comment: it is in the case if the `tab` you are removing is currently selected else it won't call.

Comment: I want to avoid the stateChanged method call on following cases(except changed in tab number):a)jTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(index) ;
b)jTabbedPane.removeTabAt(index) 
           c) this.tabbedPane.insertTab(tabTitle, null, jPanel,null,this.index);d) getTabTitile(index)